# Caddy, Docker container running IIS, and https...help needed

Tags: docker, powershell, iis, caddy

Here's my situation. I am containerizing a legacy Classic ASP application.

I'm currently working locally so I'm using Caddy along with a hosts file to handle the domain.

My hosts file looks like this.

`127.27.16.9   sub.mysite.com`

My Caddyfile looks like this.

```
sub.mysite.com:80 {
    reverse_proxy 127.27.16.9:8086
}

sub.mysite.com:443 {
    reverse_proxy 127.27.16.9:8087
    tls star_mysite_com.pem wildcard_mysite_com.key
}
```

I don't know Caddy well but the documentation said I needed my cert in PEM with a separate private key. I have a PFX but I believe PEM is all Caddy will accept.

My container works fine if I'm using http (I'm binding 80 to 8086 and 443 to 8087).  I can browse http://sub.mysite.com.

I've spent the past day trying to import different types of certificates in different ways and the only thing I've gotten to work is PFX using the specific Import-PfxCertificate.

Here's the Powershell I'm using.

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Password $pwd -FilePath "c:\cert\wildcard_mysite_com.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
New-IISSiteBinding -Name MySite-BindingInformation "*:443:sub.mysite.com" -CertificateThumbPrint $cert.Thumbprint -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\my"  -Protocol "https"
```

Running Get-Website shows the following bindings.

```
Name     ID   State      Physical Path           Bindings
----     --   -----      -------------           --------
MySite   1387 Started    c:\webcode              http *:80:
                 7529                            https *:443:sub.mysite.com sslFlags=0
```

That looks ok to me. However, when I browse to my site using https://sub.mysite.com, I get a 502 with the following Caddy log error.

```
http.log.error  read tcp 127.0.0.1:59340->127.27.16.9:8087: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.     
{"request": {"remote_ip": "127.0.0.1", "remote_port": "59338", "client_ip": "127.0.0.1", "proto": "HTTP/2.0", "method": "GET", "host": "sub.mysite.com", "uri": "/", "headers": {"Sec-Ch-Ua": ["\"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"115\", \"Chromium\";v=\"115\""], "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": ["1"], "Sec-Fetch-Mode": ["navigate"], "Accept": ["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"], "Sec-Fetch-Site": ["none"], "Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate, br"], "Accept-Language": ["en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8"], "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": ["?0"], "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": ["\"Windows\""], "Dnt": ["1"], "User-Agent": ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"], "Sec-Fetch-User": ["?1"], "Sec-Fetch-Dest": ["document"], "Cookie": []}, "tls": {"resumed": false, "version": 772, "cipher_suite": 4865, "proto": "h2", "server_name": "sub.mysite.com"}}, "duration": 0.0057207, "status": 502, "err_id": "zv6amhucn", "err_trace": "reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:1248)"}
```

If I had to guess, and that's all I can do, it's something with the cert. I'm using a PFX on my container and a PEM on Caddy. I didn't convert the PFX to PEM but rather downloaded each from Digicert. I'm going to try to Import the .cer file again and see if that might make a difference. I might try to generate the PEM and KEY from the PFX to see if that makes a difference.

Caddy certainly isn't required here. I was looking for the easiest way to do a reverse proxy on a local windows dev machine.

**Edit**

I enabled tracingFailedRequestsLogging. What's interesting is that I don't get any logs generated if I make a request from outside of my container. I get a Caddy error but no logs on the container.

I created a hosts file on my container and added

`120.0.0.1   sub.mysite.com`

and then did

`curl https://sub.mysite.com -UseBasicParsing`

and got a response that included content. It also created logs under my FailedReqLogFiles folder.

I tried going to https://sub.mysite.com:8087 (8087 maps to 443 in Docker) and this worked and the cert is valid. Something is wrong with my reverse proxy.

Comment: You are getting a response with status 502 which means the TLS certificate is working.  TLS is performed before the Request is sent and when TLS fails there is no request and no response.  Error 502 is bad gateway.  The gateway may be using a virus checker that does like the contents of the message.  I would try a simple text request and see if the error changes.  Cookie is empty and proxy may be using OAUTH which requires doing a token request and then sending the token (cookie) with each request.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 502 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.